# Is there a way to get lifted tabs in daisyUI to use the full width?

Tags: css, tabs, tailwind-css, daisyui

I am using the `tabs` in daisyUI to display a set of lifted tabs.

However the tabs 'underlining' stops after the last tab, and I'd like it to continue all the way along to the edge of the div.

[image]

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

```
<div class="tabs">
    <a class="tab tab-lifted tab-active" wire:click="omitted" id="tab1">Tab1</a>
    <a class="tab tab-lifted" wire:click="omitted" id="tab2">Tab2</a>
    <a class="tab tab-lifted" wire:click="omitted" id="tab3">Tab3</a>
    <a class="tab tab-lifted" wire:click="omitted" id="tab4">Tab4</a>
    <a class="tab tab-lifted" wire:click="omitted" id="tab5">Tab5</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Three approaches I could think of:

1. Use a final child that grows out the width of the parent that has the bottom border.

   ```html
   <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daisyui@3.5.1/dist/full.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

   <div class="tabs">
     <a class="tab tab-lifted tab-active" wire:click="omitted" id="tab1">Tab1</a>
     <a class="tab tab-lifted" wire:click="omitted" id="tab2">Tab2</a>
     <a class="tab tab-lifted" wire:click="omitted" id="tab3">Tab3</a>
     <a class="tab tab-lifted" wire:click="omitted" id="tab4">Tab4</a>
     <a class="tab tab-lifted" wire:click="omitted" id="tab5">Tab5</a>
     <span class="grow border-b border-base-300"></span>
   </div>
   ```
2. Draw the border on the parent element, using a `1px`-high linear gradient.

   ```js
   // Needed to have the `base-300` color be available in this demonstration since we are using
   // Daisy UI via CDN. In "real" usage with the Daisy UI Tailwind plugin, all the colors would
   // automatically be available for use.
   tailwind.config = {
     theme: {
       extend: {
         colors: {
           'base-300': 'hsl(var(--b3) / <alpha-value>)',
         },
       },
     },
   };
   ```

   ```html
   <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daisyui@3.5.1/dist/full.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

   <div class="tabs bg-[linear-gradient(theme(colors.base-300),theme(colors.base-300))] bg-bottom bg-no-repeat bg-[length:100%_1px]">
     <a class="tab tab-lifted tab-active" wire:click="omitted" id="tab1">Tab1</a>
     <a class="tab tab-lifted" wire:click="omitted" id="tab2">Tab2</a>
     <a class="tab tab-lifted" wire:click="omitted" id="tab3">Tab3</a>
     <a class="tab tab-lifted" wire:click="omitted" id="tab4">Tab4</a>
     <a class="tab tab-lifted" wire:click="omitted" id="tab5">Tab5</a>
   </div>
   ```
3. Add a bottom border to the parent, and pull the child tabs over the border so it lines up with them

   ```js
   // Needed to have the `base-300` color be available in this demonstration since we are using
   // Daisy UI via CDN. In "real" usage with the Daisy UI Tailwind plugin, all the colors would
   // automatically be available for use.
   tailwind.config = {
     theme: {
       extend: {
         colors: {
           'base-300': 'hsl(var(--b3) / <alpha-value>)',
         },
       },
     },
   };
   ```

   ```html
   <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daisyui@3.5.1/dist/full.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

   <div class="tabs border-b border-base-300">
     <a class="-mb-px tab tab-lifted tab-active" wire:click="omitted" id="tab1">Tab1</a>
     <a class="-mb-px tab tab-lifted" wire:click="omitted" id="tab2">Tab2</a>
     <a class="-mb-px tab tab-lifted" wire:click="omitted" id="tab3">Tab3</a>
     <a class="-mb-px tab tab-lifted" wire:click="omitted" id="tab4">Tab4</a>
     <a class="-mb-px tab tab-lifted" wire:click="omitted" id="tab5">Tab5</a>
   </div>
   ```

See all these solutions in [this Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/XExQFruhye).

Comment: Many thanks, using a final child that grows out the width of the parent that has the bottom border worked perfectly.

  <span class="grow border-b border-base-300"></span>

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class="tabs flex">
   <a class="tab tab-lg flex-auto">Tab1</a>
   <a class="tab tab-lg flex-auto">Tab2</a>
   <a class="tab tab-lg flex-auto">Tab3</a>
</div>
```

By using the Tailwind classes 'flex', you are telling the tab set div to display as a flexbox. By setting 'flex-auto' on each tab, you are causing each tab to take up as much space as it can, thus, it stretches to fit the maximum width! :)

Comment: You should add some text to explain your answer.